# Как получить ISP у IP через PHP?

Tags: php, ip, isp

Подскажите, как получить ISP у IP через PHP? Вот например для IP http://www.ip2location.com/demo/198.7.58.100 как получить значение "LeaseWeb USA Inc."?

Comment: http://www.ip2location.com/developers/php

Answer (score 1):

Можно начать отталкиваться от следующего скрипта

```
<?php
$sock = fsockopen('whois.arin.net', 43, $errno, $errstr);
fputs ($sock, "198.7.58.100\r\n");
$text = '';
while (!feof($sock)) {
  $text = fgets ($sock, 128);
  $arr = explode(':', $text);
  if($arr[0] == 'OrgName') {
    echo $arr[1]; // LeaseWeb USA Inc.
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: ARIN - это американская регистратура и их whois отвечает только на запросы по американским IP. Всего регистратур в мире 5. И их api мягко говоря отличаются

Comment: @Mike, если ARIN не может ответить, он возвращает реферер на ту регистратуру, которая может ответить - просто не стал рекурсию городить.

Comment: Ну тогда бы я рекомендовал начать с загрузки с iana.org распределения блоков по регистратурам (инфа меняется редко, стоит сохранять у себя). Что бы ненужные запросы не городить. Сразу определять регистратуру и запрашивать у нее. http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xhtml

Comment: @cheops http://www.ip2location.com/developers/php Зачем мудрить?

Comment: @E_p считаете выгрузка нескольких тестовых 100Мб баз данных (с актуальностью в 1 месяц, с перспективой покупки полных баз и выгрузки по-настоящему больших объемов), это лучше, чем отправка запроса к официальному регистратору доменного имени? И это ради одной строчки? Вынужден не согласиться.

Comment: Вернулся снова к этому вопросу. К сожалению, скрипт не совсем рабочий - например для IP 185.121.170.242 должен выдавать Zappie Host LLC, а выдаёт RIPE Network Coordination Centre. Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0):

А что же вы не зашли в их секцию для девелоперов
http://www.ip2location.com/developers/php.

Там и библиотека есть для PHP.

```
<?php 

    // Подключаем библиотеку
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $db = new \IP2Location\Database('./databases/IP-COUNTRY-SAMPLE.BIN', \IP2Location\Database::FILE_IO);
    $records = $db->lookup('8.8.8.8', \IP2Location\Database::ALL);
    echo 'ISP Name: ' . $records['isp'] . PHP_EOL;
```

А установка через composer:

**composer.json:**

> {
>       "require": {
>         "ip2location/ip2location-php": "8.*"
>       }
>     }

`> composer install`

Не нравится composer, вот ссылка на github.
https://github.com/chrislim2888/IP2Location-PHP-Module